# Expected ';' after this. , stthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

Q. I implemented MultiProvider in the manner shown below in my MAIN file. While running I am thrown the below error. Can anybody help me with this?
Thank you.

**#Error**

../../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.1/lib/src/provider.dart:358:7: Error: Expected an identifier, but got ','.
Try inserting an identifier before ','.
, stthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
^
../../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.1/lib/src/provider.dart:357:49: Error: Expected ';' after this.
if (inheritedElement == null && null is! T) {
^
../../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.1/lib/src/provider.dart:358:7: Error: Unexpected token ','.
, stthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
^
../../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.1/lib/src/provider.dart:358:9: Error: 'stthrow' isn't a type.
, stthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
^^^^^^^
../../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.1/lib/src/provider.dart:358:17: Error: Expected ';' after this.
, stthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.1/lib/src/provider.dart:358:44: Error: Expected ')' before this.
, stthrow ProviderNotFoundException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             24.4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

---

**#My main file**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Config/config.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Counters/changeAddress.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Counters/itemQuantity.dart';
import 'package:e_shop/Counters/totalAmount.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'Config/config.dart';
import 'Counters/cartItemCounter.dart';
import 'splash/splashscreen.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  EcommerceApp.auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  EcommerceApp.firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CartItemCounter()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ItemQuantityCounter()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AddressChangeCounter()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TotalAmountCounter()),
        //OR -------
        // ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: CartItemCounter()),
        // ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ItemQuantityCounter()),
        // ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: AddressChangeCounter()),
        // ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: TotalAmountCounter()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'e-Shop',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          home: SplashScreen()),
    );
  }
}
```

**#My Counter dart files (4 files almost similar to below file)**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class CartItemCounter with ChangeNotifier {
  int _counter = EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences!
          .getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList)!
          .length -
      1;

  int get count => _counter;

  Future<void> displayResult() async {
    int _counter = EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences!
            .getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList)!
            .length -
        1;

    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MultiProvider/Provider had to be provided on top of the Widget tree. i.e., inside the **runApp** widget, which got rid of the *ProviderNotFoundException.*, as now provider services are available throughout the app.

```
  Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  EcommerceApp.auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Counter()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CartItemCounter()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AddressChangeCounter()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ItemQuantityCounter()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AddressChangeCounter()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TotalAmountCounter()),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I build a provider class, I import this

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
```

instead of this

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

And out of curiosity, which package do you import in your main file?

--edit:
Maybe you can try to use a builder instead of a child in your changeNotifier, like this:

```
builder: (context, child) => MaterialApp(...)
```

Comment: I have added the imports in the main for your convenience.

Comment: I tried importing Cupertino, but still the same error.

Comment: @NikashDeka you can try my last edit, if that doesn't work, then I'm out of ideas :/

Comment: I tried it earlier, but same error!!

Comment: When I comment out some unimportant things like firebase, sharedpreferences and some of your widgets so I can run your code, everything is fine, so or your model of provder is incorrect handled with sharedpreferences, or the error is due to a piece of code I can't see. btw, why do you use provider when you store the data in sharedpreferences? So I recommend commenting out some packages and functionality until the error disappears, or you can share more code so I can take a look at it

Comment: @NikashDeka Where do you use provider? I suppose you use it in splashscreen.dart, can you show me that file?